# Mount failed. A maintenance shell will now be started

Tags: 14.04, boot, dual-boot, mount

I am dualbooting ubuntu and Windows 7.
Installation went well, but when I try to boot ubuntu, the laptop goes black for ever, when I try to wake it up, the file mounting problem appears, asking me to ignore, mount manually, or skip it.
At any rate, it ends up appearing the "mount failed. A maintenance shell will now be started", and then don't know what to do.  I have uninstalled and installed several times. I have given it 30Gb of HD space in C: partition, and well, it should work.

NOTE ADDED: Please help. I still cannot make it work!

Comment: Are you talking about a Wubi.exe install?

Comment: No. It is when I boot once installed along Windows

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see if it is of any help:

1. While booting choose the option with `Recovery mode`
2. Go to the option with `Drop to root shell prompt` and execute the following commands
3. `mount -o remount rw /`

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  When I execute the mount it tells.. you must specify the filesystem type.  I tried with the - t param but I don't get the right one...

Comment: try `auto` as the type of filesystem (other main options are `ext4` and `ext3`)

Comment: mount -t auto -o remount rw / gives me same error... I tried other combination

Comment: I guess your partition has no filesystem assigned to it. If you have a live USB/CD you can use that to check it.

Comment: Detailed disk usage show following filesystem:
/dev/loop2 19GB mounted on /
/dev/sda1 201GB (must be C:) mounted on /host
udev 1,8GB mounted on /dev
tmpfs 356MB mounted on /run